# iterate result set to create object as required

Tags: java, javabeans, resultset

[image]

Hello guys.I have following result set and now i want it to be saved in a java bean.I have two java beans(pojo).

```
public class Topic{
private int topic_id;
private String topic;
private List<SubTopic> subTopicList;

//getter setter
}
```

and

```
public class SubTopic{
    private int sub_topic_id;
private String sub_topic;
//getter and setter
}
```

Now i want to set my `Topic` object in such a way that it contains one topic and list of all its subtopic.But i am having problem on iterating the result set.To make it more clear a Topic object that includes Cardiology should have,

```
topic_id=73
topic=Cardiology
List<SubTopic> subTopic=//this includes id and name of SubTopic and SubTopic2
```

Same another object should be for Allergy,Athma,Immunology.

```
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
//now how to iterate rs to create list of topic object in required way
```

Comment: What is your question?  What are you having trouble with and what have you tried?

Comment: That's a wrong DB design !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a map to store your topics:

```
Map<Long, Topic> topicsById = new HashMap<>();
while (rs.next()) {
    Long topicId = rs.getLong(1);
    String topicName = rs.getString(2);
    Long subTopicId = rs.getLong(3);
    String subTopicName = rs.getString(4);

    Topic topic = topicsById.get(topicId);
    if (topic == null) {
        topic = new Topic(topicId, topicName);
        topicsById.put(topicId, topic);
    }
    topic.addSubTopic(new SubTopic(subTopicId, subTopicName);
}
Collection<Topic> allTopics = topicsById.values();
```